# Unable to migrate stored procedure for Crystal Reports from SQL Server to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports-2010

I have been trying to migrate a SQL Server 2005 database to MySQL 5.5.29 and having trouble with the reports done with Crystal Reports 2010. I can use the set datasource location to migrate the tables (I do have to do each one individually and rename it before it will migrate) but I got it done.

However, I'm not able to update the stored procedure as I get the message:

> *Database Connector Error: 'HY00:[MySQL][ODBC 5.1
>   Driver][mysqld-5.5.28-lof]SELECT command denied to user ... [Database
>   Vendor Code: 1142]*

I'm using the same ODBC Source as used for the tables so I don't know what I have to do to update/migrate the stored procedure.  I tried to create a new report and add a stored procedure but get the same message.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Vic

Comment: I tried to add a stored procedure named test that wasn't doing anything and I get the same error. So for some reason I'm not able to use stored procedures in Crystal 2010!

Comment: I tried using stand-alone Crystal Reports 2008 to add a mysql stored procedure and I get the same connector error as soon as I add a stored proc using Database Expert.  I can add stored procedure from a SQL Server Connection and I'm using the same connection for mysql as used to add tables.

Comment: The error still says SELECT command denied to username@IP for table proc. It seems I need to include Use Procedure Bodies=false in the connection string.  However, I'm using an ODBC connection for this Crystal Report so does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I tried "GRANT SELECT  ON mysql.proc TO user@'localhost'" and I received the error "SELECT,GRANT command denied to user 'username'@IP' for table 'proc'. Basically the same message when trying to add stored procedure Crystal.

Comment: It seems I cannot grant the select permission to mysql.proc because it is a shared server and the provider will not do it (exposes a security risk). The work-around from mysql is to use the Use Procedures Bodies = false in the connection string.  However, as stated above I don't know how to include this in an ODBC datasource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a restriction by the provider and they refuse to change it. Because of this I am not able to include stored procedures in a Crystal Report.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, the user the report is being executed as genuinely does not have access to the specified table.

The MySQL bug report [Escaped wildcard in DB name prevents user from granting database permissions](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=12008) may shed some light on why permissions may not be applied as you think they are when the db name contains an underscore.

Comment: The db name does contain an underscore but it is put there by the provider as this is a shared server.  If this is a problem why did migrate the tables work and it is only affecting stored procedures?